# Matlab crossval and cvpartition

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

I'm trying to code a leave one subject out cross validation after training my data with SVM. There are 15 subjects. I've read the crossval documentation but am still lost... Here is my code:

```
load EEG_X  %features
load EEG_Y  %label
Subject_index=2;
fea = X{1,Subject_index};
gnd = Y{1,Subject_index};
model = train(gnd', sparse(fea'));
c = cvpartition(15,'leaveout')
cvmodel = crossval('CVPartition',c)
```

I'm not sure about the relationship between cvpartition and crossval. Do I need to define a FUN function?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the expected result?